# Generate local maven repository with all dependencies using Gradle

Tags: maven, gradle

### What I currently have

```
dependencies {
    compile ...
}

task copyDependencies(type:Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'build/dependencies/'
}
```

This task copies all the required dependencies to the `build/dependencies/` directory. Inside the directory, it looks as follows:

```
/dep1-1.0.jar
/dep2-1.0.aar
...
```

So essentially what is known as `flatDir` in gradle terms.

### What I'd like to have

It's a `local maven repository` with all these dependencies, instead of a `flatDir`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to *publish* to a local directory as if it were `mavenLocal()` but in a location you specify.

In that case, I believe you just need:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "/path/to/wherever"
        }
    }
}
```

See the [Maven Publish plugin docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)

Comment: I actually just found [this](https://speakerdeck.com/bmuschko/advanced-dependency-management-with-gradle?slide=52) which describes the problem. Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a recording of the talk.
Regarding your solution, what it does is publish the built artifact, not all its dependencies.